# For example, the input: 02/26/1986 should produce the the output: Feb 26,1986. Pls Help me what is the code?

Tags: java, date, numerical

JAVA: Create a program that accepts dates in numerical form and then output them as a complete form. For example, In Terminal, i input: 02/26/1986 and i enter should produce the the output: Feb 26,1986. Pls Help me what is the code?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html  This has the answers to your question. Scroll a bit down and see the usage of Simple Date Format.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

final class SO32983650
{

  private static final DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu");

  private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, uuuu");

  public static void main(String... argv)
  {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    in.lines().map(parser::parse).map(formatter::format).forEach(System.out::println);
  }

}
```

Comment: cannot find symbol?-DateTimeFormatter